# Inverse trigonometry question

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

This is a worked example from my textbook:

> Evaluate these expressions exactly, rationalizing denominators when necessary.
>
> $\sin(\sin^{-1}\frac{4}{5})$
>
> Let $\alpha = \sin^{-1}\frac{4}{5} $
>
> Then $\sin\alpha=\frac{4}{5}$ (where the condition $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le\alpha\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ is now irrelevant.)

The part I don't understand is where they said "the condition $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le\alpha\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ is now irrelevant". Why would the restriction on the domain be lifted for this question?

Comment: It's not irrelevant, it's just that the angle $\alpha$, whose sine is equal to $\frac45$, is already within that domain. It is poor word choice by the writer. They should have said something similar to what I said, instead of using the word "irrelevant".

Comment: I suspect the reason why the author uses the word "now" is because there may have been a previous example in the book where the condition IS necessary.